# 360 degree video in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am  trying to develop an iphone application which needs to show a 360 degree video like the [one](http://theawesomer.com/360-degree-video-flight/83004/)  and rotate the video as per the phone movement. How can i do this? Is it possible to do this with normal MPMovieplayer controller?

Comment: did you get any answer for the same?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with a normal `MPMoviePlayerController`, but there are several libraries out there to achieve this. Have a look here:

- [PanoramaGL](http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/)
- [Panorama 360](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60635/Panorama-360-iPod-Touch-iPhone)

They work with OpenGL and you can embed them in your Objective-C code.

EDIT:
As @Mangesh Vyas kindly pointed out those are intended to use with fixed images only. However they might be a suitable starting point for embedding video as well, if you modify the code accordingly. They already do the handling of direction, accelerometer etc. so you don't have to implement all that yourself.

Comment: I see both the code but it is useful for panorama images. I needed for video like Gopano app does.

Comment: Sorry, yes they are intended for the use with images. My browser didn't load the video the OP linked, so it was just my assumption that you were looking for this. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Stefan i Have done this with the Help of Flex. Same thing i also tried with js file. Thanks For your effort. I am giving you bounty points.

Comment: Glad to hear you were successful! Thanks for the update and the points! :)

Comment: @Mangesh would like to know how you did this? have similar requirement. help please